# Apply error message to textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am trying to apply some validation error to controls like textbox. i initially was using qtip.js but for some reason it's not working well. so, i was trying to manually show error at the position i would like to show.
How would i exactly get the coordinates at the right-top corner of a control(eg: textbox as shown in picture) so i can show error message. i tried to use offset feature but to no avail.

```
var x = $("txtBox1").offset();
var relativeX = (e.pageX - offset.left);
var relativeY = (e.pageY - offset.top);
```

[image]

Comment: Just asking why can't you just use CSS? Also if you can provide some html I should be able to provide you an answer

Comment: I would like to apply left and top properties in css but for that i need to find the coordinates first. that is where i find difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best to just place the error right under the textbox using just plain HTML positioning.  The manual positioning using JavaScript is not necessary.

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v0k1jbug/

```
<input type="text">
<div class="error">Error</div>
```

Then if you are using JQuery you can show/hide/populate the error message as you wish.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the below could be helpful.

Idea is to have a `absolute` positioned element inside a `relative` and then to adjust the `position` based on `top` (as per your question). It can be done without even using external library.

Sample to play around with:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#validate").click(function(e) {
    $(".inputForm").find(".inputFormMessage").show();
  });
});
```

```css
.inputForm {
  position: relative;
}
.inputFormMessage {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="inputForm">
    <label for="txtBox">Enter Input:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtBox" />
    <span class="inputFormMessage">Input is not valid!</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="button" id="validate" value="Validate" />
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Another snippet to play around with (positioning is controlled by `Styles` and rendering upon `action`)

```js
window.onload = function() {

  // Attach handler to `validate` button 
  document.querySelector("#validate").onclick = function(e) {
    var isValid = false;
    var elementToCheck = null;

    // Disable if any `message` elements are active
    Object.values(document.querySelectorAll(".inputFormRowMessage")).forEach(function(element, index, array) {
      element.style.display = "none";
    });

    // Validate First name
    elementToCheck = document.querySelector("#txtBoxFirstName");
    isValid = elementToCheck.value.length > 0;
    if (!isValid) {
      // Show the error message
      document.querySelector(".inputFormRowMessageFirstName").style.display = "inline-block";
    }

    // Validate Last name
    elementToCheck = document.querySelector("#txtBoxLasttName");
    isValid = elementToCheck.value.length > 0;
    if (!isValid) {
      // Show the error message
      document.querySelector(".inputFormRowMessageLasttName").style.display = "inline-block";
    }

    // .. do other validations and stylings...
    // ...
  };

};
```

```css
.inputForm {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Tahoma;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.inputFormRow {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.inputFormRow > label {
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
.inputFormRowMessage {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  padding: 2px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  
  <div class="inputForm">

    <div class="inputFormRow">
      <label for="txtBoxFirstName">First Name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="txtBoxFirstName" />
      <span class="inputFormRowMessage inputFormRowMessageFirstName">Please enter First Name.</span>
    </div>

    <div class="inputFormRow">
      <label for="txtBoxLasttName">Last Name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="txtBoxLasttName" />
      <span class="inputFormRowMessage inputFormRowMessageLasttName">Please enter Last Name.</span>
    </div>

    <div class="inputFormRow">
      <label for="txtBoxAge">Age:</label>
      <input type="text" id="txtBoxAge" />
      <span class="inputFormRowMessage">Not a valid age format.</span>
    </div>

    <div>
      <input type="button" id="validate" value="Validate" />
    </div>
    
  </div>
```

Comment: that looks good. is there any way i can do it in css by finding the cooridnate position and applying that class?

Comment: It would really depend on how the DOM is structured. Please also take a look at  [*Current Positioning Context*](https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-positioning-19970819#Current_Context).

Comment: Since `span` is an `inline` element, it would sit near to your `textbox`; with `absolute` positioning (with negative `top`) the behavior can be easily accomplished. The display of the message depends upon the action, for example, validation, form submit etc. In order to manipulate the `span` contents `JavaScript` could be used.

Answer (score 0):

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/jchotdjk/1/

html

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" />
    <span class="error">Invalid email address</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: #9b9;
}

.input-group input{
  height: 20px;
}

.input-group .error{
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
}
```

To place the error just above the input and to the right, place the error in a span. Then you need to set the position of the error to relative and then force it up by the total height of the input which I have specified as 20px

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is the following:

Create 3 elements, a container, an `input` and an element for the error.

```
<div class="input__group">
  <input type="text">
  <span class="error">Error Message.</span>
</div>
```

Then define the following CSS:

```
.input__group {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 50px; /* Since the error position is absolute, you will need
                       to add some space, in this demo we are using a margin.*/
}

.error {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%; /* Used to place the element to 
                   the top by the total container's height (100%) */
  left: 100%; /* Used to place the element to
                 the right by the total container's width (100%) */
}
```

---

```css
.input__group {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.error {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 100%;
  color: whitesmoke;
  background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<div class="input__group">
  <input type="text">
  <span class="error">Error Message.</span>
</div>
```